# Understanding an Index/Match/Array Excel Formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I know this code works, but I'm not exactly sure how. Can someone please break this out for me? I'm assuming the "dragability" of this is due to the last part locking the first reference and not the second, but I don't understand the mechanics of what it's actually doing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
IFERROR(INDEX(BOM!G:G,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(BOM!B:B,$I$6,0)),MATCH(ROW(BOM!B:B),ROW(BOM!B:B)),""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

Comment: 1.  Array formulas should not refer to full columns.  2.  It can be simplified: `=IFERROR(INDEX(BOM!G:G,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(BOM!($B$1:$B$100)/($B$1:$B$100=$I$6),ROW(A1)),"")` and yes the `ROW(A1)` is simply a counter so when it drags down it get the second then the third.

Comment: FYI - You can also use the ["Evaluate Formula" function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) (under the "Formulas" tab/ribbon) to step through a formula. I find this helps sometimes with more complicated formulas, to see how it does what it does.

Comment: though if one has `Filter()` then: `=FILTER(BOM!G:G,BOM!B:B=$I$6)`